# Spring MVC,JdbcTemplate and Security Integration ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jdbctemplate

I am implementing Spring MVC Spring Security MySQL Integration
My Stack Trace will look like this.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:355)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:355)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
>           ... 20 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
>           ... 49 more

With reference to Spring Docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC2/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor.html

Intercepts concurrent request handling, where the concurrent result is obtained by executing a Callable on behalf of the application with an AsyncTaskExecutor.

A CallableProcessingInterceptor is invoked before and after the invocation of the Callable task in the asynchronous thread, as well as on timeout from a container thread, or after completing for any reason including a timeout or network error.

As a general rule exceptions raised by interceptor methods will cause async processing to resume by dispatching back to the container and using the Exception instance as the concurrent result. Such exceptions will then be processed through the HandlerExceptionResolver mechanism.

The afterTimeout method can select a value to be used to resume processing.

Can anyone please explain and help me out of this.

Comment: Looks like you are lacking some spring jars ... are you using maven or something else to manage dependencies ? If you do not and have this error you should contemplate using it !

Answer (score 0):

Trace clearly shows, your application is not able to find **CallableProcessingInterceptor** class. Edit your pom with below dependency and check if it is working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As mentioned above, This is MVC without MAVEN. I had added this jar file already

Comment: I think your project has issues with conflicting versions of Spring jars

Comment: All I have been using same versions of jar only

Answer (score 0):

I have just verified. On a Spring 3.2.8 release, `org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor` lies in `spring-web-3.2.8.jar`.

The error is :

```
...exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
```

That proves that *at run time* `spring-web.jar` is not in classpath, or is not same version as other spring jars. A common cause for that when not using maven, is to *declare* the jars to the compiler or IDE, not include them in `WEB-INF/lib` in the war, and not to have them in Tomcat's classpath.

As you do not use maven, it looks like you are in a *build and dependencies hell* (name is mine). Either tomcat finds other jars (typically other versions of spring) in its classpath, or your build does not include (for any reason) `spring-web-version.jar` for correct version. This may be hard to fix, but you can try :

- control is nothing looks wrong in your build process
- control if the deployed application holds proper jars with proper version
- strip down the application to remove parts until it works and re-add them one at a time in order to identify exactly what triggers the error

Or if you can do it, convert your application to use maven, and it will deal almost automatically with all those dependencies for you, warning you of incompatible versions.

But I'm afraid that **I** cannot do more for you here ...

Comment: spring-web-3.2.8.jar is already located in lib folder i cant delete it

Answer (score 0):

This exception is caused due to Spring dependent jars missing or having conflict between versions of jars
Check whether you have spring-web-X.X.X (X.X.X is the required version depending on project) jar available on your build path/Maven dependency.
If there is any duplicate jar you need to remove it.